# tomcat<N>w.exe not persisting information

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, tomcat6

I use tomcat 6 as a windows service in which I deploy my web applications. I add Java options to the server (by adding them in the Java options in Java tab after running  tomcatw.exe).
Everything works fine. The only problem is that when I restart my machine or switch the cluster machine (I have a two machine cluster but with common storage), I lose this information and my added Java options are no longer available. This happens every time I switch the machine.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "switch the machine"? Are you using shared-storage for your Windows Registry?

Comment: I am using shared storage. There are two machines which use the same storage and which are on a cluster (active / passive). When I switch from one machine to the other, I loose the information for the Java opts.

Comment: I suspect that the Microsoft Windows registry has some difficulty with this "switch". I'm not a Windows expert, so I might have no idea what I'm talking about. What I *do* know is that those Java options are stored in the Windows Registry and pulled-out upon service-launch.